# I don't find the error

Tags: xetex, errors

The code is here

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym,cancel}

% Referencias - Enlaces
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,
citecolor=red, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,format=plain,parskip=1pt,justification=centering}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,format=plain,parskip=1pt,justification=centering}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic {figure}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{etex,tikz, pgf, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.5}

\usepackage[total={18cm,21cm},left=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\parindent=0mm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch }{1.2}
\usepackage{icomma} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %activamos el paquete
\usepackage{endnotes} 
\usepackage[superscript]{cite} %las citas

\renewcommand\citeform[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}  % Ponemos las citas en azul

\let\footnote=\endnote
\def\footnotetext{\endnotetext[\number\numexpr\value{endnote}+1]}
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark 

\pagestyle{fancy} %seleccionamos un estilo
\lhead{Formulario Cónicas} %texto izquierda de la cabecera
\rhead{\thepage }
\chead{Formulario} %texto centro de la cabecera
\rfoot{Cónicas} %texto izquierda del pie
\rhead{\thepage } %número de página a la derecha
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografía}

\definecolor{gris claro}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}
\title{Formulario De Cónicas}
\author{Cristobal López Silla - Licenciado En Matemáticas}
\date{}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Cónicas}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\colorbox{gris claro}{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{Una \textbf{cónica} o \textbf{sección cónica} es un lugar geométrico que se obtiene al intersectar un plano con un cono.}}}
\end{center}
Si el plano no pasa por el vértice se obtienen las \textbf{cónicas no degeneradas}: \emph{circunferencia, elipse, parábola e hipérbola}. \\

Si el plano corta el vértice se obtienen las \textbf{cónicas degeneradas}: un punto, una recta generatriz del cono, dos rectas que se cortan en el vértice del cono.\\

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{conicas.svg}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Diferentes Cortes de un plano con un cono \\ \textbf{(1)} Parábola \textbf{(2)} Elipse \emph{(arriba)} y Circunferencia \emph{(abajo)} \textbf{(3)} Hipérbola \\ Fuente Wikipedia \cite{Con}}
\end{figure}

\section*{Circunferencia}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\colorbox{gris claro}{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{Lugar geométrico de los puntos de un plano que equidistan de otro punto fijo y coplanario llamado \textbf{Centro} en una cantidad constante llamada \textbf{Radio}.}}}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw[red, thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[right=-0.5cm, below=0.95cm, semithick, rotate=90] {diámetro}; %diámetro
    \filldraw[fill=green!20!white,draw=green!50!black](0,0)--(2cm,0) arc (0:90:2cm)--cycle; %arco
    \draw (1.25,1.55) -- (1.25,2.5) node {\small Long. Arco};
    \draw[blue, thick] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[above=0.25cm, left=0.75cm, semithick] {radio}; %radio
    \draw[green!45!black, thick] (-2,2) -- (1,-2) node[right=-0.5cm, above=0.85cm, semithick, rotate=-45] {secante}; %secante
    \draw[gray!45!black, thick] (-1,1.732) -- (-1,-1.732) node[right=0.1cm, above=0.75cm, semithick, rotate=90] {cuerda}; %cuerda
    \draw[orange, thick] (2,3) -- (2,-2) node[midway, right=0.15cm, semithick] {tangente}; %tangente
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Principales Elementos De La Circunferencia}
\end{figure}

\textbf{Longitud Circunferencia}: $L=2\cdot \pi \cdot r$\\

\textbf{Longitud Arco Circunferencia}: $L=\dfrac{2\cdot \pi \cdot r \cdot \alpha}{360^\circ}\quad / \alpha$ es el ángulo del arco.\\

\textbf{Área Circunferencia}: $A=\pi \cdot r^2$\\

\subsection*{Ecuaciones De La Circunferencia}
\textbf{\underline{Coordenadas Cartesianas}}: Sea $C=(a,b)$ el Centro de la circunferencia y $r$ su radio. Representamos la circunferencia de centro C y radio r en cartesianas como:
\[(x-a)^ 2+(y-b)^2=r^2\]
Si el centro es el origen de coordenadas se representa por:
\[x^2+y^2=r^2\]
Si además, el radio es $r=1$, se le denomina \textbf{Circunferencia Unidad} o \textbf{Circunferencia Goniométrica} $x^2+y^2=1$.\\ \\
Desarrollemos $(x-a)^ 2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ para obtener la Forma General de la Circunferencia:\\ 
\[(x-a)^ 2+(y-b)^2=r^2 \Rightarrow x^2-2ax+a^2+y^2-2by+b^2=r^2\Rightarrow x^2+y^2-2ax-2by+b^2-r^2=0\]
Definimos lo siguiente:
\[A=-2a,\quad B=-2b, \quad C=b^2-r^2\]
Lo sustituimos en la última expresión y obtenemos:
\[x^2+y^2+Ax+By+C=0\rightarrow\: Forma\: General\: De\: La\: Circunferencia\]
\textbf{\underline{Ecuación Vectorial}}: De centro $C=(a,b)$ y radio $R$, tal que $\theta\in\left[0,\, 2\pi\right[$
\[\overrightarrow{r}=\left(a+R\cdot \cos\left(\theta\right),\, b+R\cdot \sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\]
\textbf{\underline{Ecuación Paramétrica}}: De centro $C=(a,b)$ y radio $r$. Lo expresamos en forma de función:
\[f(t)=(a+r\cdot\cos(t),\: b+r\cdot\sin(t))\:\forall\: t\in[0,2\pi]\]
\newpage
\section*{Elipse}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\colorbox{gris claro}{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{Lugar geométrico de todos los puntos de un plano, tales que la suma de las distancias a otros dos puntos fijos llamados \emph{focos} es constante.}}}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);
    \draw (0,2.25) -- (0,-2.25);
    \draw (3.0,0) -- (-3.25,0);
    \draw[fill, color=blue!30!white] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2.236,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (0.1);
    \node at (0.25,0.25) {\small C};
    \draw[fill] (0,2.0) circle (0.1);
    \node[color=blue] at (0.25,2.25) {\small b};
    \draw[fill] (0,-2.0) circle (0.1);
    \node[color=blue] at (-0.25,-2.25) {\small -b};    
    \node[color=blue] at (3.25,0.15) {\small a};    
    \node[color=blue] at (-3.25,0.15) {\small -a};    
    \node[color=red!75!black] at (-2.35,0.25) {\small F1};    
    \node[color=red!75!black] at (2.35,0.25) {\small F2};
    \node[color=red!75!black] at (1.175,-0.25) {\small c};
    \node[color=red!75!black] at (1.1,1.25) {\small a};
    \node[color=red!75!black] at (-0.25,0.9) {\small b};
    \node[color=green!75!black] at (1.1,2.15) {\small P};
    \draw[color=green!75!black] (1.0,1.885618) -- (-2.236,0);
    \draw[color=green!75!black] (1.0,1.885618) -- (2.236,0);
    \draw[color=blue!75!black,dashed, very thick] (4.0249,2.5) -- (4.0249,-2.5);
    \node[color=blue!75!black] at (4.75,1.0) {$x=\dfrac{a^2}{c}$};
    \draw[color=blue!75!black,very thick] (1.0,1.885618) -- (4.0,1.885618);
    \draw[fill, blue!75!black] (4.0,1.885618) circle (0.1);
    \node[color=blue!75!black] at (4.25,1.88) {\small D};
    \draw[color=blue!75!black] (3.0,0) -- (4.0,0);
    \draw[fill, blue!75!black] (4.0,0) circle (0.1);
    \node[color=blue!75!black] at (4.25,0) {\small d};
    \draw[fill] (3.0,0) circle (0.1); %punto a
    \draw[fill] (-3.0,0) circle (0.1); %punto -a
    \draw[fill, red!75!black] (-2.236,0) circle (0.1); %punto F1
    \draw[fill, red!75!black] (2.236,0) circle (0.1); %punto F2
    \draw[fill, green!75!black] (1.0,1.885618) circle (0.1); %punto P
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Principales Elementos De La Elipse\\ \textbf{Área:} $A=2\cdot\pi\cdot a\cdot b$}
\end{figure}

\subsection*{Elementos de una Elipse}
La elipse es una curva plana y cerrada, simétrica respecto a 2 ejes perpendiculares entre sí, que son los semiejes: \\
\textbf{\underline{Semieje Mayor}}: En la figura es el que va de \textbf{-a} hasta \textbf{a}. Su valor es $2\cdot a$ \\[2.5pt]
\textbf{\underline{Semieje Menor}}: En la figura es el que va de \textbf{-b} hasta \textbf{b}. Su valor es $2\cdot b$ \\[2.5pt]
Si la elipse es vertical, entonces se tiene:\\
\textbf{\underline{Semieje Mayor}}: Va de \textbf{-b} a \textbf{b}. Su valor es $2\cdot b$\\
\textbf{\underline{Semieje Menor}}:Va de \textbf{-a} a \textbf{a}. Su valor es $2\cdot a$\\
Miden la mitad de los ejes mayor y menor, respectivamente. \\
\textbf{\underline{Focos}}: Son 2 puntos que están a la misma distancia del centro de la elipse. 
\[d(F_1,\, C)=d(F_2,\, C)\Rightarrow\: Distancia\: Focal\]
Dado un punto cualquiera P de la elipse, se cumple:
\[d(P,\, F_1)+d(P,\, F_2)=2\cdot a\]
Si consideramos $F_1=(-c,0),\: F_2=(c,0)$, siendo $c=d(C,F_1)=d(C,F_2)$, la distancia de uno de los focos al centro de la elipse. Se define:\\
\textbf{\underline{Distancia Focal}}: Es el valor $2\cdot c$\\
Se cumple la siguiente ecuación fundamental (Ver el triángulo de la figura 2):
\[a^2=b^2+c^2\]
La fórmula cambia cuando la elipse es vertical a:
\[b^2=a^2+c^2\]
\emph{No hace falta que la memorices, sólo hace falta que recuerdes el Teorema de Pitágoras.}\\
\textbf{\underline{Excentricidad $(\epsilon)$}}: Indica la forma de la elipse, cuanto más cerca de cero más se parecerá a una circunferencia. O lo que es lo mismo, si $a=b\Rightarrow\epsilon=0\Rightarrow Circunferencia$ \\
$\epsilon=\frac{c}{a}\: ; \quad 0\, \leq\,\epsilon\, \leq\, 1$ \\
Como $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\Rightarrow \epsilon=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}}=\sqrt{1-(\frac{b}{a})^2}$ \\
\textbf{\underline{Directrices}}: $\epsilon=\dfrac{\overline{PF}}{\overline{PD}}$ \\
Si definimos $f=\overline{PF}\qquad d=\overline{PD}\Rightarrow \epsilon=\dfrac{f}{a}\quad \epsilon=\dfrac{a}{d}\Rightarrow d=\dfrac{a}{\epsilon}\Rightarrow d=\dfrac{a}{\frac{c}{a}}\Rightarrow d=\dfrac{a^2}{c}$\\
\emph{Luego la directriz para una elipse horizontal centrada en el origen es la recta vertical:} $x=\dfrac{a^2}{c}$\\
Si el centro elipse es $C(h,\: k)$ tenemos:\\
\textbf{\underline{Directriz Elipse Horizontal}}: $x=h+\dfrac{a^2}{c}$\\
\textbf{\underline{Directriz Elipse Vertical}}: $y=k+\dfrac{b^2}{c}$
\subsection*{Ecuaciones De La Elipse}
\textbf{\underline{Coordenadas Cartesianas}}: Consideremos el centro de la elipse por $C=(x_0,y_0)$, con a,b sus semiejes. Se puede expresar la ecuación de la elipse en Cartesianas de \emph{forma explícita} como:
\[\dfrac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1\]
\textbf{\underline{Paramétricas}}: Si $\theta\in [0,2\pi[$ Lo expresamos como función paramétrica: \\
\[f(\theta)=(x_0+a\cdot\cos(\theta),\, y_0+b\cdot\sin(\theta))\]

\newpage
\section*{Parábola}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\colorbox{gris claro}{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{Lugar geométrico de los puntos de un plano equidistantes a una recta dada, llamada \textbf{Directriz}, y a un punto exterior a ella llamado \textbf{Foco}.}}}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick](0,-2) parabola (-2,2) (0,-2) parabola (2,2);
    \node[color=red!75!black] at (0.6,-2.15) {\small vértice};
    \draw[very thick,blue!75!black](0,-3.5) -- (0,2);
    \node[color=blue!75!black] at (0.35,2.0) {\small eje};
    \draw[very thick,red!75!black](-1.4142,0) -- (1.4142,0);
    \node[color=red!75!black] at (-.5,0.35) {\small lado recto};
    \node[color=blue!75!black] at (0.5,-0.25) {\small foco};
    \draw[very thick,orange!75!black](-2,-3) -- (2,-3);
    \node[color=orange!75!black] at (-1.25,-2.8) {\small directriz};
    \draw[very thick,green!75!black](0,0) -- (1.75,1.0625);
    \draw[very thick,green!75!black](1.75,1.0625) -- (1.75,-3);
    \draw[fill] (0,-2) circle (0.1);
    \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Principales Elementos De La Parábola}
\end{figure}
Tomemos la siguiente nomenclatura:
\[V=(h,k)\: V\acute{e}rtice\quad F=Foco\quad p=d(F,V)\rightarrow Distancia\quad Focal\quad R=Longitud\quad Lado\quad Recto\]
\textbf{\underline{Lado Recto}:} Segmento de la parábola que pasa por el foco y es paralelo a la directriz.\\
\textbf{\underline{Foco Parábola Vertical}:} $F=(h,k+p)$\\
\textbf{\underline{Foco Parábola Horizontal}:} $F=(h+p,k)$\\
\textbf{\underline{Directriz Parábola Vertical}:} $y=k-p$\\
\textbf{\underline{Directriz Parábola Horizontal}:} $x=h-p$\\
\textbf{\underline{Propiedad Del Lado Recto}:} $R=4\cdot p$\\
\begin{center}
\fbox{\colorbox{gris claro}{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{La parábola es la única sección cónica que cumple que su excentricidad es 1, $e=1$. Luego \emph{todas las parábolas son semejantes}.}}}
\end{center}
\newpage
\subsection*{Ecuaciones De La Parábola}
Denotemos $V=(x_v,\: y_v)$ el \emph{Vértice de una parábola cualquiera}. \\
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{\underline{Vértice En El Origen Y Eje Vertical}} $\Rightarrow y=a\cdot x^2$
\item \textbf{\underline{Vértice En El Origen Y Eje Horizontal}} $\Rightarrow x=a\cdot y^2$
\item \textbf{\underline{Vértice No En El Origen y Eje Vertical}} $\Rightarrow (y-y_v)=a\cdot (x-x_v)^2$
\item \textbf{\underline{Vértice No En El Origen y Eje Horizontal}} $\Rightarrow (x-x_v)=a\cdot (y-y_v)^2$
\item \textbf{\underline{Forma Explícita y Eje Vertical}} $\Rightarrow y=ax^2+bx+c$
\item \textbf{\underline{Forma Explícita y Eje Horizontal}} $\Rightarrow x=ay^2+by+c$
\item \textbf{\underline{Forma Respecto Distancia Focal (p)}} $\Rightarrow (x-x_v)^2=4p(y-y_v)$
\end{enumerate}
\subsection*{Características De La Parábola}
Consideremos la forma $y=ax^2+bx+c$\\
\textbf{Si} $\mathbf{a>0}\rightarrow$ Parábola hacia \emph{arriba}, el vértice es un \emph{Mínimo}.\\
\textbf{Si} $\mathbf{a<0}\rightarrow$ Parábola hacia \emph{abajo}, el vértice es un \emph{Máximo}.\\
\textbf{Calcular Vértice}: $x_v=\dfrac{-b}{2a}$. Para calcular $y_v$ basta sustituir $x$ por $x_v$ en $y=ax^2+bx+c$ \\
\newpage
\section*{Hipérbola}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\colorbox{gris claro}{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{Lugar geométrico de los puntos de un plano tales que el valor absoluto de la diferencia a sus distancias a dos puntos fijos, llamados \textbf{focos}, es igual a la distancia entre los \textbf{vértices}, la cual es una constante positiva.}}}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10!white},                    
                show background rectangle,
                information text/.style={font=\small,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,fill=yellow!50!white,inner sep=1ex}] 
 \tikzset{
        small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.5},
        }
    \begin{axis}[
        %grid=major,
        legend entries={$x^2-y^2=1$, , , , ,$y=x$, $y=-x$},
        minor tick num = 3,
        scale only axis,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=center,
        domain=-5:5,
        y domain = -5:5,
        axis on top,xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
        legend style={ at={(1.03,1)},
        anchor=west,fill=yellow!50!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\tiny},
        title={\centering \underline{\textbf{Hipérbola $x^2-y^2=1$}}},
        title style={font=\small, color=black}
    ] 
        \addplot[smooth, color=red] ({cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
        \addplot[smooth, color=red] ({-cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
        \addplot[ultra thick, color=blue!80!black, domain=-1:1] {0}; 
        \addplot[smooth,ultra thick, color=blue!60!black, domain=0:1] {1-x}; 
        \addplot[smooth,ultra thick, color=blue!60!black, domain=0:1] ({0},{x}); 
        \addplot[smooth, color=blue!60!black, dashed] {x}; 
        \node[font=\small, color=blue!60!black,rotate=45] at (axis cs:3.5,4.0) {$y=x$};
        \addplot[smooth, color=blue!60!black, dashed] {-x}; 
        \node[font=\small, color=blue!60!black,rotate=-45] at (axis cs:-3.5,4.0) {$y=-x$};
        \addplot[smooth, color=green!60!black, very thick] ({0.707},{x});
        \node[font=\small, color=green!60!black] at (axis cs:1.45,3.6) {$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$};
        \addplot[smooth, color=green!60!black, very thick] ({-0.707},{x});
        \node[font=\small, color=green!60!black] at (axis cs:-1.45,3.6) {$x=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$};
        \node[small dot, color=blue!60!black] at (axis cs:1,0) {};
        \node[font=\small, color=blue!60!black] at (axis cs:0.95,0.25) {a};
        \node[small dot, color=blue!60!black] at (axis cs:-1,0) {};
        \node[font=\small, color=blue!60!black] at (axis cs:-0.8,0.25) {-a};
        \node[small dot] at (axis cs:0,0) {};
        \node[font=\small] at (axis cs:0.25,0.25) {C};
        \node[small dot, color=yellow!60!black] at (axis cs:1.4142,0) {};
        \node[font=\small, color=yellow!60!black] at (axis cs:1.65,0.25) {$F_1$};
        \node[small dot,color=yellow!60!black] at (axis cs:-1.4142,0) {};
        \node[font=\small, color=yellow!60!black] at (axis cs:-1.65,0.25) {$F_2$};      
    \end{axis}
    \draw[xshift=10.25cm,yshift=3cm]
    node[right,text width=4cm,information text]
    {
    \textbf{Semiejes}\\
    Es el segmento $[-a,\: a]=[-1,\: 1]$\\
    El otro semieje es imaginario\\
    \textbf{Vértices}\\
    $(\pm a,0)=(\pm 1,0)$\\
    \textbf{Focos}\\
    $c^2=a^2+b^2\rightarrow c=\sqrt{2}$\\
    $F_1(\sqrt{2},0)\quad F_2(-\sqrt{2},0)$\\
    \textbf{Excentricidad}\\
    $e=\frac{c}{a}\rightarrow e=\sqrt{2}$\\
    \textbf{Asíntotas}\\
    $y=\pm\frac{b}{a}x\rightarrow y=\pm x$\\
    \textbf{Directrices}\\
    $x=\pm\frac{a^2}{c}\rightarrow x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Hipérbola Canónica $x^2-y^2=1$}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\subsection*{Elementos De La Hipérbola}
Si consideramos una hipérbola centrada en $C=(h,\: k)$, tenemos lo siguiente:\\
\textbf{\underline{Hipérbola Horizontal}} $\Rightarrow \dfrac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$\\
\textbf{\underline{Hipérbola Vertical}} $\Rightarrow \dfrac{(y-h)^2}{b^2}-\dfrac{(x-k)^2}{a^2}=1$\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{\underline{Semieje Hipérbola Vertical}}: Segmento $[-b,\: b]$, el otro es imaginario.\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Semieje Hipérbola Horizontal}}: Segmento $[-a,\: a]$, el otro es imaginario.\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Vértices Hipérbola Vertical}}: Puntos $V(0,\:\pm b)$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Vértices Hipérbola Horizontal}}: Puntos $V(\pm a,\: 0)$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Distancia Focal Hipérbola}}: $c^2=a^2+b^2\rightarrow c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Focos Hipérbola Horizontal}}: $F(h\pm c,\: k)$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Focos Hipérbola Vertical}}: $F(h,\: k\pm c)$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Excentricidad Hipérbola Horizontal}}: $\epsilon=\frac{c}{a}$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Excentricidad Hipérbola Vertical}}: $\epsilon=\frac{c}{b}$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Asíntotas Hipérbola Horizontal}}: $y=k\pm \frac{b}{a}\cdot x$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Asíntotas Hipérbola Vertical}}: $x=h\pm \frac{a}{b}\cdot x$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Directrices Hipérbola Horizontal}}: $x=h\pm \frac{a^2}{c}$\\
\item \textbf{\underline{Directrices Hipérbola Vertical}}: $y=k\pm \frac{b^2}{c}$\\
\end{enumerate}
\subsection*{Ecuaciones De La Hipérbola}
Denotemos el centro de una hipérbola por $C=(h,\: k)$. \\
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{\underline{En Cartesianas Y Horizontal}} $\Rightarrow \dfrac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$
\item \textbf{\underline{En Cartesianas Y Vertical}} $\Rightarrow \dfrac{(y-h)^2}{b^2}-\dfrac{(x-k)^2}{a^2}=1$
\item \textbf{\underline{Canónica Vertical}} $\Rightarrow \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$
\item \textbf{\underline{Canónica Horizontal}} $\Rightarrow \dfrac{y^2}{b^2}-\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}=1$
\item \textbf{\underline{Paramétricas}}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{\underline{Tipo I}}: $f(t)=(h\pm a\cdot\cosh t,\: k+b\cdot\sinh t)\:\forall\: t\in \mathbb{R}$
\item \textbf{\underline{Tipo II}}: $f(t)=(h+a\cdot\sec t,\: k+b\cdot\tan t)\:\forall\: t$
\end{enumerate}
\item \textbf{\underline{Compleja}}: $\mid z-w_1 \mid - \mid z-w_2 \mid =2\cdot l$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{thebibliography}{5}
  \bibitem{Con}\href{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secci%C3%B3n_c%C3%B3nica}{Wikipedia Cónicas.}
  \bibitem{Cir}\href{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circunferencia}{Wikipedia Circunferencia.}
  \bibitem{Eli}\href{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elipse}{Wikipedia Elipse.}
  \bibitem{Par}\href{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A1bola_(matem%C3%A1tica)}{Wikipedia Parábola.}
  \bibitem{Hip}\href{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip%C3%A9rbola}{Wikipedia Hipérbola.}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If I compile with Xelatex in texmaker all works good, but if I compile pressing F1 key I obtain an error about `$` message

```
! Missing $ inserted.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\maththreesuperior ->{^3}
l.57
```

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$`. But perhaps the `}` is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}`. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}`.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always try to make a *minimal* example. your error message is

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.57 

?
```

which means it is on line 57, just after `\maketitle` so all your document after that line can be replaced by simply `\end{document}`. After discarding all your document you can discard the packages it was using, which makes it much easier to test.

You have specified `latin1` If your file is in latin1 (= iso-8859-1) you get no error but if it is in UTF-8, and you specify latin1 then you do.

If you use pdflatex you need

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

If you use xelatex you must not use `inputenc` at all.

Comment: ok, thanks. I've changed to utf8 and I don't have this error message, but I've got this other error message:  ! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg. It seems I cannot export svg images with pdflatex, but I can use svg with xetex, oh what a mess!! Is there any way to fix this one? Thanks

Comment: ok, i've converted to png and all works good. thanks